# Java object to be accessed outside of its scope

Tags: java, scope

I'm taking a java class and as part of the requirements for my next program I need to have a button that instantiates my object and then I perform various tasks with it. My problem is that once I create my object within the actionlistener that receives the click on the button how do I now use that object?

```
public class Create implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        AdvancedAcmeTaxi taxi = new AdvancedAcmeTaxi(Double.parseDouble(input.getText()));
        selection.setEnabled(true);
        btnCreate.setEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

So in the above code I have my custom listener and I then create the object but due to the scope I only have access to it here. How do I fix this? Please note that for the purview of this class there are no controllers. Just the Model and View. This is a nested class in my GUI class. It is instantiated by
    btnCreate.addActionListener(new Create());

Comment: FYI: Objects don't have scope.  Variables have scope.  `taxi` is not an object, it is a variable that holds a reference to an object.  The answers are telling you to assign the value of taxi (i.e., the reference) to other variables that have wider scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the object to be a member field in the class:

```
public class Create implements ActionListener {

   private AdvancedAcmeTaxi taxi;

   // getter method for field
   public AdvancedAcmeTaxi getTaxi() {
      return taxi;
   }

   public Create() {
      ...
   }
   ...

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       taxi = new AdvancedAcmeTaxi(Double.parseDouble(input.getText()));;
       selection.setEnabled(true);
       btnCreate.setEnabled(false);
   }

}
```

Upon adding the listener, you can access the field as follows:

```
Create listener = new Create();
btnCreate.addActionListener(listener);

...
AdvancedAcmeTaxi taxi = listener.getTaxi();
```

Comment: Should note though that I had to mark taxi and the getter as static. Thanks for the quick response though

Comment: There's no need to make them static. You already have an instance of the listener created using a constructor. Why not simply call the getter on the instance that was created?

Comment: Like Create.getTaxi() and use that in place of a variable? That's what I tried and Eclipse told me that I had to make the return value of the getter static.

Comment: @JoesphOlliff: it's a mistake to make either the field or the getter static. You need to fix something else so that this isn't needed. 1+ to this answer. And no, Eclipse didn't tell you to make it static. Re-read the error message carefully. The real fix is to fix the rest of your code so static isn't needed.

Comment: @JoesphOlliff I updated the answer to illustrate what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle this. One is to get a reference to the main GUI, and then call a method to it:

```
public class Create implements ActionListener {
    private MainGui mainGui;

    public Create(MainGui mainGui) {
        this.mainGui = mainGui;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        AdvancedAcmeTaxi taxi = new AdvancedAcmeTaxi(Double.parseDouble(input.getText()));;
        selection.setEnabled(true);
        btnCreate.setEnabled(false);

        mainGui.setTaxi(taxi);
    }
}
```

You would have to pass a reference of the Current MainGui into this class when you call its constructor, and this would assume that the MainGui has some method that will be able to handle your Taxi instance (here I call `setTaxi(...)`).

Another way is to have your *Control* class, the Create class above, modify the program's *Model* object. The View (the GUI) would have listeners into the model and would change its display when the Model changes. This is called the MVC or Model-View-Control design pattern, and it can be quite useful in allowing you to separate your concerns.

Comment: Not sure how to implement this. I should have mentioned that for the purview of this class we are not using controllers just the Model and view. This class is nested in my GUI.

Comment: @JoesphOlliff: you're telling me information that should have been (and now should be) part of your original question as this is all relevant to a decent solution. Please consider improving your question, telling us more about just where this code is located, what your main GUI structure looks like -- anything that we need to know in order to understand your problem. Please avoid assuming that we know what we can't see.

Comment: So very sorry. First time using stackoverflow to ask my own question. Will modify question shortly. However @manouti 's answer (after making all related parts static) solved my problem. Again though very sorry and for lesson learned will modify question

Comment: @JoesphOlliff: no problem and welcome to the site. If either of our answers helped you, then consider up-voting them. If manouti's answer solved your problem, then please both up-vote it and mark it as the correct answer.